# Uploading multiple files with Flask App Builder

Tags: python, html, flask, flask-wtforms, flask-appbuilder

Creating a simple front end with Flask where I can select multiple files and runs some calculations on them.

Currently I am using the code below, but it is only good for 1 file, `#do something` is where the conversion happens;

```
class Sources(SimpleFormView):
    form = MyForm
    form_title = 'This is my first form view'
    message = 'My form submitted'

    def form_get(self, form):
        form.field1.data = 'This was prefilled'

    def form_post(self, form):
        x = #do something
        return self.render_template('test.html', table = x ,name='TEST')
```

The form basically lets me type in the path as shown below:

```
from wtforms import Form, StringField
from wtforms.validators import DataRequired
from flask.ext.appbuilder.fieldwidgets import BS3TextFieldWidget
from flask.ext.appbuilder.forms import DynamicForm


class MyForm(DynamicForm):
    Path = StringField(('Field1'),
        description=('Your field number one!'),
        validators = [DataRequired()], widget=BS3TextFieldWidget())
```

I am trying to select multiple files from my local machine and then process them together. Much like how we attach files using Gmail;

1. Option to select file path
2. Open file browser
3. Store file path
4. Process 1 and 3 repeats till hit threshold or submitted.

I am currently using Flask App Builder to get my front end right.

Answer (score 0):

You can use this HTML form which will allow the user to select multiple files:

```
<form method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data" action="/upload">
  <input type="file" name="file[]" multiple="">
  <input type="submit" value="Upload Files">
</form>
```

Then in your upload function you use getlist function from Flask.

```
@app.route("/upload", methods=["POST"])
def upload():
    uploaded_files = flask.request.files.getlist("file[]")
    print uploaded_files
    return ""
```

I would recommend appending your do something function to accept a list of all of the files as an input. Then do something like

```
For file in uploaded_files:
    Process the files
```

Comment: I've actually read that solution. But because I'm using flask app builder the decorators and stuff seem to be different

Comment: I'll edit this answer in a little while with implementation for flask app builder.

Comment: Appreciate it. Thanks! I'm having trouble trying to design Web frameworks.

Comment: Thanks, yea I wold call the function with a for. But have any ideas for the flask app builder implementation yet?